# Unit testing specific components in Angular

Tags: angular, unit-testing

In My Angular project, I have an Angular project within a parent Angular project - So the second angular project(Child) is like a module app. When I test the application it always takes the parent `app.component.spec.ts` for tests within Jasmine Karma. I have tried navigating via the terminal to the specific folder and run `ng test` but still the parent `app.component.spec.ts` gets tested?

Any idea's how to just test specific components?

Answer (score 0):

Change `it` to `fit` to just test this test.

Change `it` to `xit` to skip this test.

Change `describe` to `fdescribe` to test all the `it`s inside of this `describe`.

Change `describe` to `xdescribe` to skip all the `it`s inside of this `describe`.